# NDSolve warning: step size is effectively zero

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a set of coupled differential eqns., but getting the errors as mentioned in the title.

```
replace = 
  {Subscript[m, ϕ] -> 10^-5, Γ -> 10^-11, λ -> 0.01, ξ -> -1, m -> 10^-21,  
   k -> 10^59, Subscript[M, P] -> 1};

V[t_] := 1/2 Subscript[m, ϕ]^2  ϕ[t]^2  /. replace ;

R[t_] := Subscript[M, P]^-2 (4 V[t] - ϕ'[t]^2/(k^2 a[t]^2)) /. replace;

χi[t_] := ((- ξ R[t] - m^2)/λ)^(1/2) /. replace;

eqna = 
   ϕ''[t] + 2 a'[t]/a[t] ϕ'[t] + k a[t] Γ ϕ'[t] + k^2 a[t]^2 D[V[t], ϕ[t]] /. replace;

eqnb = 
  χ''[t] + 2 a'[t]/a[t] χ'[t] + k^2 a[t]^2 λ χ[t]^3 + k^2 a[t]^2 m^2 χ[t] + 
  k^2 a[t]^2 ξ R[t] χ[t] /. replace;

eqnc = 
  k  Subscript[ρ, r]'[t]/a[t] + 4 k  a'[t]/a[t]^2 Subscript[ρ, r][t] - 
  Γ ϕ'[t]^2/a[t]^2 /. replace;

eqnd = 
  a'[t]/a[t] -
    Sqrt[
      1/(3 Subscript[M, P]^2) 
        (1/2 ϕ'[t]^2 + k^2 a[t]^2 V[t] + k^2 a[t]^2 Subscript[ρ, r][t])]
/. replace;

sol1 = 
  NDSolve[
    {eqna == 0 , eqnb == 0, eqnc == 0, eqnd == 0,  ϕ[-60 ] == 15 , 
     ϕ'[-60] == 0, χ[-60] == χi[-60], χ'[-60] == 0, 
     Subscript[ρ, r][-60] == 10^-20, a[-60] == Exp[-70]}, 
    {ϕ, χ, Subscript[ρ, r], a}, {t, -60, 5}] // FullSimplify
```

> Error:NDSolve::ndsz: At t == -60., step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

I think other solutions to this problem [ndsz : step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110626/ndsz-step-size-is-effectively-zero-singularity-or-stiff-system-suspected) didn't match with my problem.

Also, while plotting:
`Plot[{Evaluate[Abs[χ[t]] /. sol1]}, {t, -60, 5},  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True]`
error is appearing as :
InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {-59.9987} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.

Note that -59.9 is inside the range.

Comment: Regarding the second error: notice that the results from NDSolve are interpolating functions with a domain $[-60, -60]$, i.e. the integration did not proceed at all, and the only value available is -60. Is your system stiff? Do you have a singularity at t=-60? This is a pretty common problem: what have you tried specifically (with code) and what was the result?

Comment: Oh I see. But I got the plot(may be through extrapolation), though not the correct one as expected. I don't see any singularity at t=-60. I was trying to solve a physics problem: evolution of some quantities such as scale factor of the Universe, some quantum fields etc. with time(conformal time). I didn't get the result as required. Earlier I was trying to do the same problem in a different variable(physical time), but I think computation was too heavy there [large range](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224268/how-to-run-ndsolve-over-a-large-range-without-freezing).

Comment: @surujjd Let check coefficients of your system: there are $10^{108}$ in `eqna` , $10^{118}$ in `eqnb` and `eqnd`.   How we can handle this with numerical methods?